# The Help Center contains outdated names and URLs

Tags: bug, help-center, https

Almost all URLs in the [Help Center's on-topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) use HTTP, when Stack Exchange has migrated entirely to HTTPS. Additionally, the link to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is using its old name, "IT Security".

These should be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now done, all link updated, and corrected the old name of Information Security.

Thanks for your report !

Comment: One link is still HTTP: The first SuperUser link.

Comment: @forest oops and done :)